How do I fix this WebSocket error in my app?
I have code below that proxies a WebSocket connection:
app.ws("/", async (socket) => {
    api = new WebSocket("wss://example.com/?v=2", [], {
        headers: {
            "Origin": "https://example.com"
        }
    });
    api.on("open", async () => {
        api.on("message", async data => socket.send(data.toString()));
        socket.on("message", async data => (api.readyState === api.OPEN) && api.send(data));
    });
});

But sometimes I receive this error:
C:\Users\admin\project\app.js:64
        socket.on("message", async data => (api.readyState === api.OPEN) && api.send(data));
                                                                                ^

TypeError: api.send is not a function

Is there any way to fix this without using try catch blocks? Please comment a solution with example code if you can help!
